# Parameters getting reinitialized after restore from checkpoint - Tensorflow Object Detection API

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, object-detection, object-detection-api

I am trying to train an object detector with the tensorflow (1.14) Object Detection API on my GPU.
Therefor i am using a pretrained model from the tf model zoo.

The training config is:

```
fine_tune_checkpoint: "/home/daniel/Desktop/venv/models_latest/research/object_detection/training/experiments/faster_rcnn_3/model.ckpt"
  from_detection_checkpoint: true
  num_steps: 1
  load_all_detection_checkpoint_vars: true
  fine_tune_checkpoint_type: "detection"
```

Once i train one image for one step this is the output:

```
I1213 13:22:52.498878 140298995029824 saver.py:1280] Restoring parameters from /home/daniel/Desktop/venv/models_latest/research/object_detection/training/experiments/faster_rcnn_pets_3/model.ckpt
I1213 13:22:53.028416 140298995029824 session_manager.py:500] Running local_init_op.
I1213 13:22:53.295333 140298995029824 session_manager.py:502] Done running local_init_op.
Summary of weights: -7745.5962343811989
I1213 13:22:58.046248 140298995029824 learning.py:779] Starting Session.
I1213 13:22:58.180775 140292514621184 supervisor.py:1117] Saving checkpoint to path training/experiments/faster_rcnn_pets_3/training/model.ckpt
I1213 13:22:58.185102 140298995029824 learning.py:793] Starting Queues.
I1213 13:22:59.394556 140292506228480 supervisor.py:1099] global_step/sec: 0
I1213 13:23:04.981492 140291348625152 supervisor.py:1050] Recording summary at step 0.
I1213 13:23:09.964757 140298995029824 learning.py:519] global step 1: loss = 6.9496 (11.652 sec/step)
I1213 13:23:10.085421 140298995029824 learning.py:802] Stopping Training.
I1213 13:23:10.085600 140298995029824 learning.py:810] Finished training! Saving model to disk.
Summary of weights: -7745.7172140061102
```

It seems like the parameters are restored from the checkpoint but i guess the "running local_init_op" is somehow overwriting them?

Furthermore what do the big negative weights mean?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're claiming the weights are being reinitialized.
At first the weight summary is -7745.596, and after a single step the summary is -7745.717.
It seems it's working fine.

Comment: I might forgot to mention that after i run the same model (newly copied from the model zoo repo) with the same settings result in a different weight before(!) the first run. 
For example it would be -7744.123. 
Which seems weird to me because both runs should have restored the same results from the same files i got from the model zoo.